# Is the phrase 'the best out of bests' correct?

Tags: adverbs, adjectives, nouns, superlatives

Quite commonly used in India, the phrase **"the best out of bests"** is claimed to denote that you get something that is unmatched and of above-all quality. However, I avoid using this most of the times. But then...

> Is the phrase 'The best out of bests' correct and accepted in English?

If that is correct, how does the word 'bests' function there? An adverb or a noun?

Comment: It seems to be a mangling, misunderstanding of *the best of the best*.

Comment: A related idiom is [_cream of the crop_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cream+of+the+crop).

Comment: @J.R. That reminds me of [crème de la crème](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_de_la_cr%C3%A8me), which I found in a movie I've watched. Thanks for the comment, which brings back good memories!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more common form would be

> The best of the best.

Where the second best denotes the collection of best [items], the first best denotes the best one in that collection.

I would not dare to claim that "the best out of the bests" is incorrect, but I would assume it is localized Indian English.

If we accept it as correct, "best" is a noun, denoting exactly the same object as in "best of the best": the best [item] among the collection of best [items].